# Which Key value, Nosql database can ensure no data loss in case of a power failure?

Tags: in-memory-database, aerospike, key-value-store, database, nosql

At present, we are using Redis as an in-memory, fast cache. It is working well. The problem is, once Redis is restarted, we need to re-populate it by fetching data from our persistent store. This overloads our persistent 
store beyond its capacity and hence the recovery takes a long time.

We looked at Redis persistence options. The best option (without compromising performance) is to use AOF with 'appendfsync everysec'. But with this option, we can loose last second data. That is not acceptable. Using AOF with 'appednfsync always' has a considerable performance penalty.

So we are evaluating single node Aerospike. Does it guarantee no data loss in case of power failures? i.e. In response to a write operation, once Aerospike sends success to the client, the data should never be lost, even if I pull the power cable of the server machine. As I mentioned above, I believe Redis can give this guarantee with the 'appednfsync always' option. But we are not considering it as it has the considerable performance penalty.

If Aerospike can do it, I would want to understand in detail how persistence works in Aerospike. Please share some resources explaining the same.

We are not looking for a distributed system as strong consistency is a must for us. The data should not be lost in node failures or split brain scenarios.

If not aerospike, can you point me to another tool that can help achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a database problem, it's a hardware and risk problem.**

All databases (that have persistence) work the same way, some write the data directly to the physical disk while others tell the operating system to write it. The only way to ensure that every write is safe is to wait until the disk confirms the data is written.

There is no way around this and, as you've seen, it greatly decreases throughput. This is why databases use a memory buffer and write batches of data from the buffer to disk in short intervals. However, this means that there's a small risk that a machine issue (power, disk failure, etc) happening after the data is written to the buffer but before it's written to the disk will cause data loss.

On a single server, you can buy protection through multiple power supplies, battery backup, and other safeguards, but this gets tricky and expensive very quickly. This is why distributed architectures are so common today for both availability and redundancy. Distributed systems do not mean you lose consistency, rather they can help to ensure it by protecting your data.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to use a database that allows for replication so that every write goes to at least 2 different machines. This way, one machine losing power won't affect the write going to the other machine and your data is still safe.

You will still need to protect against a power outage at a higher level that can affect all the servers (like your entire data center losing power) but you can solve this by distributing across more boundaries. It all depends on what amount of risk is acceptable to you.

Between tweaking the disk-write intervals in your database and using a proper distributed architecture, you can get the consistency and performance requirements you need.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Aerospike.  You can choose to have your namespace stored in memory, on disk or in memory with disk persistence.  In all of these scenarios we perform favourably in comparison to Redis in real world benchmarks.

Considering storage on disk when a write happens it hits a buffer before being flushed to disk.  The ack does not go back to the client until that buffer has been successfully written to.  It is plausible that if you yank the power cable before the buffer flushes, in a single node cluster the write might have been acked to the client and subsequently lost.

The answer is to have more than one node in the cluster and a `replication-factor` >= 2.  The write then goes to the buffer on the client and the replica and has to succeed on both before being acked to the client as successful.  If the power is pulled from one node, a copy would still exist on the other node and no data would be lost.

So, yes, it is possible to make Aerospike as resilient as it is reasonably possible to be at low cost with minimal latencies.  The best thing to do is to download the community edition and see what you think.  I suspect you will like it.

Comment: Hey Ben, I'm sure you mean "replication factor >= 2".

Answer (score 0):

I believe aerospike would serves your purpose, you can configure it for hybrid storage at namespace(i.e. DB) level in *aerospike.conf*
which is present at ***/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf***

For details please refer official documentation here: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to be at the mercy of the latency of whatever the storage medium is, or the latency of the network fabric in the case of cluster, regardless of what DBMS technology you use, if you must have a guarantee that the data won't be lost. (N.B. Ben Bates' solution won't work if there is a possibility that the whole physical plant loses power, i.e. both nodes lose power.  But, I would think an inexpensive UPS would substantially, if not completely, mitigate that concern.)  And those latencies are going to cause a dramatic insert/update/delete performance drop compared to a standalone in-memory database instance.

Another option to consider is to use NVDIMM storage for either the in-memory database or for the write-ahead transaction log used to recover from.  It will have the absolute lowest latency (comparable to conventional DRAM).  And, if your in-memory database will fit in the available NVDIMM memory, you'll have the fastest recovery possible (no need to replay from a transaction log) and comparable performance to the original IMDB performance because you're back to a single write versus 2+ writes for adding a write-ahead log and/or replicating to another node in a cluster.  But, your in-memory database system has to be able to support direct recovery of an in-memory database (not just from a transaction log).  But, again, two requirements for this to be an option:
1. The entire database must fit in the NVDIMM memory
2. The database system has to be able to support recovery of the database directly after system restart, without a transaction log.

More in this white paper http://www.odbms.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/IMDS-NVDIMM-paper.pdf